# A technical problem with the server created an error + magento

Tags: magento2

We are using the Linux server and In Magento Panel we are facing below error,

**A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.**

[image]

The client had run 777 commands to /var partition by mistakenly but I realised that and reverted the changes and corrected the permissions. But still getting the same error.

Comment: I have tried multiple solutions provided by the Google search box.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is resolved after mapped domain entry with IP address in hostfile on the local machine.

Previously, I was checking domain through preview option from **Plesk**.

Something issue with the **Plesk**.

Comment: can you please explain the solution a bit more??

Comment: Please confirm you are getting the same error after clicking on preview button in plesk?